# Organize a large-ish dataset efficiently for reporting

Tags: database-design, data-structures, nosql, bigdata

So the data hierarchy is pretty simple:

```
Account >> SubAccount >> Category >> Product
```

I need to pull a **daily** statistic (which is just a number, lets call it daily-performance) for each product. There can be tens of accounts, tens of subaccounts, hundreds of categories, and ***millions*** of products.

The API that lets me do this is of the form

```
GetCurrentPerformance(Product)
```

Now, in a web based dashboard, I need to be able to show a time-vs-performance for any product, category, subaccount, and account. I also need to be able to raise alerts if any product's performance changes drastically (say by more than 30%) since the last fetch of `GetCurrentPerformance(Product)`.

I'm building this solution on the cloud, preferably on AWS. I'm trying to decide how to best store my daily fetched data. Here is what I have considered:

1. Put everything in a database (RDBMS). Concerned about how quickly the table size will grow out of hand.
2. Maintain a flat-file per product, append day's performance to this file. Compute the statistic for category, subaccount, and account while fetching (average), and maintain a file per category, sub-account, and account too. **Concern**: Files will need to be stored on S3, and S3 does not support append. Makes the overall pull-file, append-data, push-file very time consuming.
3. Maintain a single file for each day's data (across all products). Then in a batch job, compute the stats for each product, category, sub-account, and account. Maintain a file/database so that all files don't have to be referenced for the average computation. **Concern:** To show the timeline for a particular product, need to read hundreds of files.
4. A No-SQL database? Don't have any experience with this.

This seems like a very simple problem - but I'm confused about the best way to proceed. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the current vs. the previous performance and don't need any historical performance statistics, then the following will work fine in an RDBMS:

```
create table product_performance (
  product_id integer primary key,
  current_perf number,
  previous_perf number
);
```

You can then set the performance by executing:

```
update product_performance
set    current_perf = :new_perf,
       previous_perf = current_pref
where  product_id = :product;
```

If you want to keep histoical performance (so you can track change over time), you'll need something like this:

```
create table product_performance (
  product_id integer,
  performance_date date,
  performance number,
  is_current char(1), --optional, may improve the performance of finding current perf easier
  primary key (product_id, performance_date)
);
```

Each new performance value is just an insert of the product and date.

Whichever method you use, it may be better to raise alerts when setting the new performance, rather than waiting for the dashboard get query to be re-run.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your detailed reply! I need to preserve historical performance values. I wonder if using an RDBMS based solution is the best way to tackle this - given that i'll have millions of rows everyday.

Comment: You can build an RDBMS solution to manage this that will scale well, provided your queries are properly indexed. If you find that your dashboard isn't performing as well as you need when keeping historical data, you could always implement both solutions in separate tables.